# How to anti-alias an image in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, image, antialiasing

I have a Flex component with a background image. The image is sharp in the beginning, but is jagged whenever I scale the component using scaleX and scaleY. How would I make the image anti-alias so that, it it's scaled to 0.75, the lines are smooth, not jaggedy?

[Here is the image](http://img195.imageshack.us/i/constructiono.png/)

[Here is the scaled version](http://img188.imageshack.us/i/68053636.png/)

[And the unscaled (good) one](http://img146.imageshack.us/i/84990127.png/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load the image with an Image component, you can cast the content property of the component to a Bitmap and then set smoothing to true. Unfortunately, the image component doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. However, it's rather easy to hack in.

Here is a tutorial to show you how to create such a component:
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=4001

However, if this is set using the backgroundImage style of a component, you just might be out of luck unless you override updateDisplayList and perform the drawing of the bitmap yourself by using Graphics.beginBitmapFill (which does provide smoothing support).

Why smoothing of images doesn't have better support (such as different interpolation methods) in Flex (and subsequently, Flash) boggles my mind. At least pixel bender filters will help a bit by letting us implement such filters ourselves.

Comment: Great! Now I'll just do some layering to get rid of the backgroundImage.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions of your Bitmap are both either n^2 or n^8, then the Flash player will automatically use a technique called mip-mapping that will dramatically improve the look (and performance) of scaled bitmap images.